# how to convert .csv file so that it is suitable for the program "dendroscope", which reads a .txt file or .newick file

Tags: csv

I have converted my .csv file into a .txt file so that I can open it on the program Dendroscope. However, it does not work and produces an error code that says

> Execution Halted: null.

I have looked online on how to convert my data into a .newick file, however the code just does not seem to work for it.

I am new to converting files to these types, so if anyone has knowledge on this topic, please let me know!

Thank you again.

Comment: You can convert a csv file to text file by simply running `head --lines=<no_of_lines> csv_file.csv > text_file.txt` on terminal.

Comment: And why is this question tagged `r`?

Comment: Please provide a sample snippet of the csv-input and the desired newick-output or text-output since the data might be re-formatted somehow.

Comment: M,0.455,0.365,0.095,0.514,0.2245,0.101,0.15,15
M,0.35,0.265,0.09,0.2255,0.0995,0.0485,0.07,7
F,0.53,0.42,0.135,0.677,0.2565,0.1415,0.21,9
M,0.44,0.365,0.125,0.516,0.2155,0.114,0.155,10
I,0.33,0.255,0.08,0.205,0.0895,0.0395,0.055,7
I,0.425,0.3,0.095,0.3515,0.141,0.0775,0.12,8 @albert and the thing is I can't create the newick output

Comment: @Narendra sorry, i forgot to clarify that I am using R to analyze the data set I have, and I had found some r packages that supposedly can convert the file to a newick, however these techniques did not work. I have also tried converting the file to a .txt using standard techniques and they were also no good

Comment: Nevermind. I have figred it out. Say you have an output of data in hierarchical clustering in r, and call it out4, then you can use a package called ape, save the file as .phylo, and then create a tree as a .newick file. I have list the steps below:                                                                                                   library(ape)
my.tree <- as.phylo(out4)
write.tree(phy=my.tree, file="WardDabalone.newick")